# Web Analytic reports for storage usage

Tags: web-analytics

I went to site collection > settings > Web Analytic report and I did not see "Storage Usage" link on the left Nav.
http://portal.company.com/sc/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=SummaryReport&l=s
[image]

However, When I click changed the url to be below then I could see the additional Nav for "Search" and "Storage Usage". Is this bug or what?

http://portal.company.com/sc/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=StorageTrendsReport&l=sc
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behaviour.

In Site Settings there is two links to Web Analytics reports
[image]

At the Site level you only have the reports in your first picture. At the Site Collection level you have the reports in your second picture.